# Remove all controls in a flowlayoutpanel in C#

Tags: c#, flowlayoutpanel

I'm building a flow layout panel whose each control represents for a room. I want to reload all room by removing all controls in the panel and adding new controls.

I used:

```
foreach(Control control in flowLayoutPanel.Controls) 
{
    flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Remove(control);
    control.Dispose(); 
}
```

but some of controls couldn't be removed.

I tried to find a solution on the internet but found nowhere.

Could any body help?

Comment: Was there an error, such as a thrown exception or message in the Output window? If so, please add that to the question?

Comment: There was no exception or message in the Output window, Akton. Just one thing, some of controls were still displayed in the panel.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Properly disposing of, and removing references to UserControls, to avoid memory leak](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610535/properly-disposing-of-and-removing-references-to-usercontrols-to-avoid-memory)

Answer (score 13):

According to MSDN, you can clear all controls from a `ControlCollection` (such as a `FlowLayoutPanel`) by [calling the `Clear()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.clear.aspx). For example:

```
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
```

Be aware: just because the items are removed from the collections does **not** mean the handlers are gone and must be disposed of properly less you face memory leaks.

Comment: By far the simplest and fastest. I didn't use this at first because I needed to retain some panels while clearing the rest. But the other methods were too slow thus I added the panels I needed to keep to a list and re-added them after the clear, thanks.

Comment: Yeah. this method is a fast and a clean way to remove all the controls in a flowlayoutpanel. Please mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 12):

That's because you are removing the controls from the same list you are iterating. Try something like this

```
List<Control> listControls = flowLayoutPanel.Controls.ToList();

foreach (Control control in listControls)
{
    flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Remove(control);
    control.Dispose();
}
```

Maybe not like that, but you get the idea. Get them in a list, then remove them.

Comment: You need to have System.Linq on your usings. If you still don't have it after that, you need to cast the object. In this case 'flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Cast<Control>().ToList()'

Answer (score 6):

Note: this is a working solution based on the previous comment, so credits to that person :)

This worked for me:

```
List<Control> listControls = new List<Control>();

foreach (Control control in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
{
     listControls.Add(control);
}

foreach (Control control in listControls)
{
     flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(control);
     control.Dispose();
}
```

There is probably a better/cleaner way of doing it, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an easy and quick solution. Here it is.

```
while (flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Count > 0) flowLayoutPanel.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
```

Comment: As mentioned in most other answers, no Dispose = memory leak