# Persistant Winform User controls and out of memory exception

Tags: vb.net, winforms, memory, memory-leaks, resources

I have a Winform application that I am using with WCF and SQL.   Part of the program that the users use to create a report will dynamically create custom user controls and place a reference to them into a hashtable that I maintain.   Then as the user navigates through the report by selecting nodes on a treeview, I load and unload the User Controls into a panel.

Here is the code I use to create them and place them into the Collection

```
    ucIncidentInstance = New ucIncidentMR(IncidentReport, IncidentReportGUID)
    ucIncidentInstance.Tag = "IncidentMR"
    ucIncidentInstance.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    Globals.ControlTable.Add(IncidentReportGUID, ucIncidentInstance)
    Globals.GlobalNode.Nodes.Add(IncidentReportGUID, "Incident Report")
```

Here is the code that moves them in and out of the Panel on the form as the user navigates through the treeview

```
    If Globals.ControlTable.ContainsKey(e.Node.Name) Then
        panelMain.Controls.Clear()
        panelMain.Controls.Add(CType(Globals.ControlTable(e.Node.Name), UserControl))
    Else
        If e.Node.Name = "MainNode" Then
            panelMain.Controls.Clear()
        End If
    End If
```

And here is the code I use in the forms Closing event to try to clean up the memory when the User closes this case.    I?ve done it with and without the .Dispose() line and the = Nothing line.    This code does get executed but does not seem to help.

```
    For Each item In Globals.ControlTable
        item.Value.Dispose()
    Next

    Globals.ControlTable.Clear()
```

When I go into a memory profiler, the controls stay in memory even though the form that created them has been unloaded from memory.   The profiler reports that the control listed above has held memory of 8818k.  When a report is closed and another is opened, the held memory for this control increases by 8818k.   And continues to increase by that amount for each report that is opened.   As you can imagine, people opening and closing a lot of reports eventually get an out of memory exception.

Comment: Looks to me at first glance that you are just diposing of your myControl: myControl.Dispose() and not the object it's being created from. Can you not just call Globals.ControlTable(item.Key).Dispose()?

Comment: I tried that method, but the behavior didn't change.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Properly disposing of, and removing references to UserControls, to avoid memory leak](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610535/properly-disposing-of-and-removing-references-to-usercontrols-to-avoid-memory)