# UserControl inside Panel inside UserControl not working

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, panel

I am having some trouble creating the template of my application :

I am making some dynamic parts of forms and I use a panel in which I include my User Control according to the choice of the user. The panel has the same size as the user control but it doesn't work at runtime. The panel in which the UC is included is inside another UC also.

I tried `autoSize = true`, fixed size and many things but I don't know why it goes like this. Any idea?

Some parts of my code to load the User Control :

```
 UC_panel.Controls.Clear();
 UC_ADDRESS uca = new UC_ADDRESS();


 uca.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
 uca.AutoSize = true;
 UC_panel.Controls.Add(uca);
```

[My UserControl for the address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpCc2.png)

[At runtime it goes bigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRgiJ.png)

Comment: This is all quite normal and important that it happens that way.  Set the panel's Font property if you want to override it.  And fix the [nasty bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12630186/17034).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you set

```
uca.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

and also

```
uca.AutoSize = true;
```

(which is redundant)

it is possible that some other container has its `AutoScaleMode` set to `Font` and its font size is bigger.

Comment: Thanks ! It was it ! The AutoScaleMode was set to Font inside the groupboxes !

Comment: @J. Vanbergen  If you haven't, do follow the suggestion of Hans Passant because that `UC_panel.Controls.Clear();` is bound to cause trouble.