# Error when try to clear all colored lable in a panel

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

[image]

I want to clear all object in that panel except my green colored button and my score lable. In other word, i want to clear all red and blue lable. But when i try to do it with foreach, didn't work properly (only clearing half of my lable)

Here is my code, i dont know what's wrong in here.

```
foreach (Control coloredLable in panel1.Controls)
{
   if (coloredLable is Label && coloredLable.Text == "")
   {
       if (status == false){
           panel1.Controls.Remove(coloredLable);
       }  
   }
}
```

I already make sure that all of my colored lable doesn't have any text inside it, but yet its still didn't work properly. Can anybody tell me what is wrong in here ?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: its sometimes only clearing left side lable, sometimes only clearing right side lable (not all side)

Comment: What is the `status`?

Comment: How are you setting `status`

Comment: oh i forget to explain it, status variable will be false if my button collide with colored lable and it will clear all the colored lable

Comment: if my button collide with right side lable, it will clear only left side. Otherwise if my button collide with left side lable, it will clear only right side lable.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12630186/17034) shows how to do this correctly.  That question is about a bug you have not discovered yet, you *must* use Dispose() instead of Remove().

Comment: @Verlander store, Is any update? If your question has been solved , you can click '✔' to mark the appropriate reply as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the following code to remove the unnecessary label in your panel.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var controls = panel1.Controls;
            for (int i = 0; i < controls.Count; i++)
            {
                if (controls[i] is Label&&controls[i].BackColor!=Color.Green&&controls[i].Text=="")
                {
                    panel1.Controls.Remove(controls[i]);
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing the action of calling the dispose method after the remove to release all the resources used by the control:

```
panel1.Dispose();
```

Comment: umm i don't want to remove the panel, i just want to remove the colored lable inside the panel

Comment: sorry that should be your panelButton.